# unexpectedly generate getter and setter in eclipse

Tags: java

```
public class GetterAndSetter {
    private int bestScore;
    private int cDate;

    //use eclipse generate getter and setter
    public int getBestScore() {
        return bestScore;
    }
    public void setBestScore(int bestScore) {
        this.bestScore = bestScore;
    }
    public int getcDate() {//why not be getCDate?
        return cDate;
    }
    public void setcDate(int cDate) {//why not be setCDate?
        this.cDate = cDate;
    }
}
```

May it will result in reflect failed? Why eclipse will do it, I don't know why?

Comment: It might be because there is only one character before the first uppercase. This is only a guess of course, I never saw that behavior myself. A confirmation with the standard notation of Bean might confirm that

Comment: @AxelH Is there a setting to change it? If not, this question's opinion-based. No one can say why the Eclipse developers decided to use that style except the developers themselves.

Comment: @Michael This should be confirmed, unfortunatly at the office we are still using Eclipse Galileo .... but it should be in the template, the same place where we can define the automated comment for method, class.

Comment: The root cause is: you use identifiers with abbreviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the problem of eclipse it is the logic of getter and setter.

it is correct, but for a good practice don't capitalize first two letters, you can take a look about that here [Java Tip #6 - Don't capitalize first two letters of a bean property name](http://futuretask.blogspot.com/2005/01/java-tip-6-dont-capitalize-first-two.html)

> This is in our java standards. You should not create a java bean
>   property name that begins with a capital letter in the 1st two places.
>   **It can lead to confusing results**. We had this happen a few times &
>   finally added it to our standards & enforce it in code reviews. One
>   place we saw problems was in struts. The form bean properties are used
>   in the JSP page, but the Struts framework has to use the getter() &
>   setter() to interact with the bean. This mapping happens based on the
>   java bean spec & in certain cases can cause a method not found error
>   if the developer doesn't name the method just right. The java bean
>   spec provides guidelines on how to map between property and the
>   associated getter() & setter().